# What's the different between ng-click='selectRow($index)' and ng-click='selectedRow = $index' in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

myController:

```
$scope.items = [
{name: 'item 1', description: 'desc001'},
{name: 'item 2', description: 'desc002'},
{name: 'item 3', description: 'desc003'},]

$scope.selectRow = function (index) {
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
}
```

CSS:

```
.select {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
```

HTML 1:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click='selectRow($index)' ng-class="{select:$index == selectedRow}">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

HTML 2:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click='selectedRow = $index' ng-class="{select:$index == selectedRow}">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Why the HTML-1 works but HTML-2 not work correctly?
what's the different between them?

Comment: ng-repeat creates a new scope for each element, when you do `selectedRow = $index` in your second example, it works, but only on the current scope of the line, not the parent scope where you need it, to watch it more clearly you could do `$parent.selectedRow = $index` which will work but is not really optimized, the best approach here is your first one

Comment: Do you have selected row predfined in your controller? Im cant remember was this required in case lke this

Comment: DotDotDot is correct!

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click='selectRow($index)'` will call function named selsectRow() and pass it the index of the row.

`ng-class="{select:$index == selectedRow}`  this expression will change the name of the class of this directive based on the result of the boolean operation `$index == selectedRow`.